# Rails: Creating A record and then reading it instantly issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a record and then pushing the id of the newly created record in a queue, from the after create filter.

From another script I am reading the ids from the queue and reading the db record for the ids instantly.

```
record = Model.find(id)# this is giving error: Couldn't find record with ID 8732
```

I am using rails 2.3.14 with mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experience is known as a race-condition.

Your second script or worker library is trying to access the record before it has been entirely written ("committed"), as ilan pointed out.

A common solution to this problem is using an [**after_commit**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit) callback instead of after_create / after_save etc.

An example from the [Article on Rails BestPractices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/695-use-after_commit).

Before:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :asyns_send_notification

  def async_send_notification
    NotificationWorker.async_send_notification({:notification_id => id})
  end
end

class NotificationWorker < Workling::Base
  def send_notification(params)
    notification = Notification.find(params[:notification_id])
    user = notification.user
    # send notification to user's friends by email
  end
end
```

After refactoring using after_commit lifecycle hooks:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :asyns_send_notification, :on => :create

  def async_send_notification
    NotificationWorker.async_send_notification({:notification_id => id})
  end
end
```

Further reading: [after_commit in the Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit).

Comment: Thanks! after_commit callback is not available in rails 2 by default,you need to use a gem for it. The solution that I am using in my case is to use 'sleep' for some time period before making the read query for the newly created record.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the query result `"SELECT * FROM Model WHERE id=8732"` is on cache.

You should try to "reload" the query :

```
record = Model.find_by_id(id, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason has to do with transaction isolation levels.  Although you can read the entry that you just inserted, another process can't until the transaction is committed.  This commit happens after the controller returns.